# How to suggest the idea of unisex bathrooms to my company?

Tags: united-states, bathroom

At my company, my company works across a number of floors.  The bathrooms on my floor are private and only support one person at a time.  The thing is, about 90% of the individuals working on this floor are male (myself included).  I've found that typically the bathroom is occupied when I need to go, while the women's restroom is usually unoccupied.  This means I'm walking up or down to other floors to use another restroom.  It's not a huge deal, but it's getting old quickly.

A previous company I worked for fixed this problem by having unisex bathrooms for individual bathrooms like this.  I'd like to make this suggestion, however I know having males/females share the same bathroom facilities can invoke all sorts of political emotion these days in America.  I'm wondering if it would be in my best interest to make this suggestion and attach my name to it.  I'm not trying to make any sort of political statement with this request, I'd just like to be able to consistently use a bathroom close to me, when I need to go!

**How can I bring the idea of having unisex bathrooms to management in a way that is most likely to be accepted?**

Comment: why are you talking about "political emotion"? You're not asking for a specific resolution to the mid-east conflict, nor are you asking them to take a particular stance on, say, gun control.

Comment: I've taken the "should I" from your question title - because I think you've got a good "how do I" question, and it seems people a cueing their close votes without reading the whole question

Comment: You should send them exactly the post you made here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The bathrooms on my floor are private and only support one person at a
>   time.
>
> A previous company I worked for fixed this problem by having unisex
>   bathrooms for individual bathrooms like this.
>
> How can I bring the idea of having unisex bathrooms to management in a
>   way that is most likely to be accepted?

With single-person restrooms, it makes no sense at all to designate some as "for women" and some "for men".

Just approach HR (or management) and say something like "I've noticed that the men's rooms are often occupied. In a previous company they solved this problem by having unisex bathrooms. Can we do that here?"

Comment: Emphasize they're single person bathrooms. It's like having a male and female handicap bathroom. It makes no sense. Handicap bathrooms are already unisex and nobody's going crazy

Comment: I've worked in places where a separate, closed, garbage bin was available for sanitary napkins and tampons, but only in the women's bathroom. You might want to check if that will be an issue, so you won't be caught by surprise if they argue that they don't want to pay for extra bins.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the political culture of your company. You might want to discuss it with some of your co-workers (in a non-argumentative way) and see how they feel.  If you get the sense that your proposal would create tension, then I'd suggest you enjoy the exercise.